# How to write an NSPredicate For CoreData to-many relationship

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nspredicate

I have 2 levels of `UITableViews` in a Navigation Hierarchy. On the first page is a `UITableView` that displays all the instances of `Equipment` using a `NSFetchedResultsController` which works great. On the second page I want to get back all the `Note` entities for a specific piece of `Equipment` so I can show them in a `tableView`.

How do I write a `NSPredicate` to only return the relevant notes?

[image: Table Relationship]

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    //Init Fetch Request
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    //Entity the NSFetchedResultsController will be managing
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Note" 
                                              inManagedObjectContext:self.myContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    //Sort Descriptors
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"noteTime" 
                                                                    ascending:YES];//Primary Sort
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"noteText" 
                                                                    ascending:YES];//Secondary Sort
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, 
                                                                sortDescriptor2, 
                                                                nil];

    //Set Sort Descriptors
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // limit Fetch to notes that belong to myEquipment
    //self
   // NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"item.name like '%@'", self.item.name]];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:PREDICATE GOES HERE];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];



    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:10];

    NSFetchedResultsController *frc = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest    
                                                                          managedObjectContext:self.myContext 
                                                                            sectionNameKeyPath:nil 
                                                                                     cacheName:@"Equipment"];
    //Set the Delegate Property
    frc.delegate = self;
    _fetchedResultsController = frc; 

    //Release Local Memory
    [sortDescriptor1 release];
    [sortDescriptor2 release];
    [sortDescriptors release];
    [fetchRequest release];

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [core data documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002484-SW3) and [the predicate programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001794-SW3) you should see  that you have to do something like

```
Equipment *equipment = // your equipment was passed from the previous tableview controller
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"equipment == %@", equipment];
```

Comment: Doesn't this lead to a logically false fetch request?
The query would be (equipment == <Equipment: 0x00000000> (entity: Equipment...)